# "SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file" using a memory SQLite database in Knex,

Tags: sqlite, knex.js

I'm getting `Knex:Error Pool2 - Error: SQLITE_CANTOPEN: unable to open database file` when runnnig a mocha test with Knex/SQLite

My knexfile:

```
module.exports = {
    test: {
        client: 'sqlite3',
        connection: {
            filename: ':memory:',
        }
    }
    ...
```

The only reference I find when I google is to someone who mispelled ':memory'.

How should I debug this? Is there a way to turn on verbose logging for knex/SQLite?

I believe the error happens in the initialization, before the tests, and before the `beforeEach()`. When I switch from sqlite3 to mysql (which we use in our dev setup), it just works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that knex wasn't properly initialized.

I had

```
var knexfile = require('../knexfile');
var knex = require('knex')(environment);
// instead of require('knex')(knexfile[enviornment])
```